# Trying to fetch from the local Next.js API in getStaticProps and my request is being redirected to the login page

Tags: node.js, express, next.js

I have a custom server that has multiple middlewares and one of those middlewares handles authentication. I have an API route that gets some data from another API and my request must be authorised.

When I fetch using `getServerSideProps` the request is authenticated, and I get a proper response, but using `getStaticProps` it gets redirected to the login page.

```
    export const getLiveData = async () => {
      const res = await fetch(
        'https://live-api-needs-auth.com',
      )

      const data = await res.json()

      return data
    }

    export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
      const { rows, columns } = await getLiveData()

      return {
        props: { rows, columns },
      }
    }
    
    export async function getStaticProps(context) {
      const res = await axios.get(`/api/table`)

      const { rows, columns } = res.json()

      return {
        props: { rows, columns },
      }
    }
```

I'm using the local Next.js API as a proxy to get the real data from the live API. Middlewares are used to authorise the request and I don't know how I can fetch in `getStaticProps` so that the second fetch from getLiveData to have the auth in place.

Comment: You should not make an axios request to an internal API route in `getStaticProps`. Instead, directly import the logic used inside your API route.